# How to use password with special chars in postgressql .pgpass file

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

How to use password with special chars like repl#stg$1*2 in postgressql .pgpass file?
db1:5433:replication:repl:repl#stg$1*2
I added entry like this in .pgpass but it's prompting for password when I connect.

Comment: There is no problem with those special characters in the password.  The problem is probably with "replication", which is kind of a magic name.  Are you trying to connect as a replication user, or to a database named "replication"?  Please show the command line or configuration line involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only one quoting rule for `.pgpass` according to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html):

```
 If an entry needs to contain : or \, escape this character with \.
```